# Jenkins Job DSL for pipelineJob missing parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

am using a Jenkin's Job DSL pipelineJob to create a new job, and I need to pass three vparameters to the new job. Here is my DSL code:

```
pipelineJob("cronjob/${ACTION}_${ENVRIONMENT_NAME}_environment_CRONJOB") {
  parameters {
    stringParam("ENVRIONMENT", "${ENVRIONMENT_NAME}")
    stringParam("INSTANCE", "${INSTANCE_NAME}")
  }
  triggers {
    scm("${SCHEDULE}")
  }
  definition {
    cpsScm {
      scm {
        git {
          remote {
            url("<my github URL>")
            credentials("my_credential_Id")
          }
          branch('*/develop')
        }
      }
      scriptPath("myhome/code/single-${ACTION}")
    }
  }
  disabled()
}
```

Here ACTION, ENVRIONMENT_NAME, and INSTANCE_NAME are the Active Choice Parameters of the DSL job. It creates a new job, and the parameters have the correct values from this job.

[image]

The myhome/code/single-${ACTION}:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    }
    stages {
        stage('Run inflate') {
            steps {
                script {
                  if (env.ENVIRONMENT != "Select a environment" && env.INSTANCE == "Select a instance") {
                        echo "Now for env.... ${env.ENVIRONMENT}"

                        ansiblePlaybook become: true,
                        colorized: true,
                        credentialsId: 'my_credential_ID',
                        extras: "-e environment_name=${env.ENVIRONMENT}",
                        installation: 'ansible',
                        inventory: 'ansible/hosts',
                        playbook: "ansible/scripts/single-action.yml"
                  }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the created job, it does not take the values assigned to the parameters, and part of the output is:

```
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Run inflate)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
Now for env.... null
[Pipeline] echo
```

The `env.ENVIRONMENT` is null, instead of `test_1` as shown in the job. Because the parameters do not have values, the Ansible playbook failed next.

How can I make the job to pick up the parameters values?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `params.ENVIRONMENT` & `params.INSTANCE` instead of the `env.` prefix.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. unfortunately it still gives me ```null``` after I changed them to ```params.ENVIRONMENT``` and ```params.INSTANCE```. What else I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a typo in the pipelineJob code. The correct one should be:

```
pipelineJob("cronjob/${ACTION}_${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}_environment_CRONJOB") {
  parameters {
    stringParam("ENVIRONMENT", "${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}")
    stringParam("INSTANCE", "${INSTANCE_NAME}")
  }
  triggers {
    scm("${SCHEDULE}")
  }
  definition {
    cpsScm {
      scm {
        git {
          remote {
            url("<my github URL>")
            credentials("my_credential_Id")
          }
          branch('*/develop')
        }
      }
      scriptPath("myhome/code/single-${ACTION}")
    }
  }
  disabled()
}
```

and it works!